# pound(#) sign in directory name: in Java How to read it

Tags: java, xslt, directory, transformation

The ClassLoader doesn't find me the file. It throws a:

> javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: 
>   javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.io.FileNotFoundException:

I was trying to do the follwoing:

```
TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(new StreamSource("C:\\dev\\workspace\\test1\\a#b\\Browser-Email.xslt"))
```

Comment: Also, format your code by indenting at least four spaces. You can use the "101\n010" button on the text entry bar.

Answer (score 3):

That is because the [`StreamSource(string)`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/stream/StreamSource.html#StreamSource%28java.lang.String%29) constructor takes an URI, not a file name and `#` has special meaning in URIs:

> **StreamSource**
>
> `public StreamSource(String systemId)`
>
> > Construct a StreamSource from a URL.
> >
> > **Parameters:**
> >     `systemId` - Must be a String that conforms to the URI syntax.

You can use

```
new StreamSource(new File("C:\\dev\\workspace\\test1\\a#b\\Browser-Email.xslt"))
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

Here is workaround for above problem
https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4294586